# inheritance with jibx

Tags: xml-parsing, jibx

I have an input xml, which i need to parse and bind using JibX.
We make use of a value in a specific node() of our xml to determine the type of child class that has to be initialized.

*sample.xml*

```
<MainClass>
    <TypeCode>ChildClassType</TypeCode>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ChildClassOne_Attribute1></ChildClassOne_Attribute1>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ChildClassOne_Attribute2></ChildClassOne_Attribute2>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ChildClassTwo_Attribute1></ChildClassTwo_Attribute1>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ChildClassTwo_Attribute2></ChildClassTwo_Attribute2>
    <!--Optional:-->
    <ChildClassThree_Attribute></ChildClassThree_Attribute>
</MainClass>
```

Is is possible in JibX to parse the above xml and initialize one of the three classes - ChildClassOne, ChildClassTwo, ChildClassThree, based on the 'TypeCode'.

My end result should look like,

```
Class MainClass{
    String TypeCode
}
```

If my TypeCode is  "TypeOne" I need "ChildClassOne" to be initialized

```
Class ChildClassOne extends MainClass{
    ChildClassOne_Attribute1;   
    ChildClassOne_Attribute2;
 }
```

If my TypeCode is  "TypeTwo" I need "ChildClassTwo" to be initialized

```
Class ChildClassTwo extends MainClass{
    ChildClassTwo_Attribute1;   
    ChildClassTwo_Attribute2;
 }
```

If my TypeCode is  "TypeThree" I need "ChildClassThree" to be initialized

```
Class ChildClassThree extends MainClass{
    ChildClassThree_Attribute;      
 }
```

Is this possible in JibX or am i asking too much??

Thanks in advance
Praveen

Comment: good tutors if so http://jibx.sourceforge.net/binding/tutorial/binding-tutorial.html

Comment: I had gone through this site earlier, but was unable to find a solution to my specific problem. Could you please be more specific.

Comment: @praveenps how you solved this issue. Please help me in this

Comment: Got solution for it